# Applying li:nth-child selector to total li count, not resetting with new ul's

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors

I have a number of ul's following one another and need to keep it that way, but I would also like to alternate the li background-color across all of these ul's. Everything I have tried to target li's globally, or from a higher up container has not worked and instead does the default behavior of applying the even/odd styling based on what number child it is related to the parent, which frequently is just a single item.

Is this possible? I could also assign even/odd classes in PHP as I generate the output but I feel like there's a way to do this in CSS and I'm just not familiar enough with it to figure out how. Maybe I'm just not using the right terms in my searching too but I haven't found any results on google.

Some of these ul's may have nested ul's within them as well but I do not want to target those lists for this styling, just `.container > ul.topLevel > li`.

Failed attempts:

```css
.uList > li { background: #58708D; }
.uList > li:nth-child(odd) { background: #4A4A4A; }

.ContentShell .uList > li:nth-of-type(odd)  {
    background: #4A4A4A;
}
.ContentShell .uList > li:nth-of-type(even) {
    background: #58708D;
}

.ContentShell > div > .uList > li:nth-child(odd)    {
    background: #4A4A4A;
}

.ContentShell > div > .uList > li:nth-child(even)   {
    background: #58708D;
}
```

JSFiddle showing problem: https://jsfiddle.net/q56h4qz9/2/

I would like the colors to alternate back and forth even though they are in different ul's

Comment: `li:nth-child(odd/even)`

Comment: That's what I originally tried but with each new ul it resets to showing the odd styling. So if I have three ul's in a row with just one item I'll get three of the same styling in a row instead of alternating

Comment: @sweaver2112 I added a jsfiddle better showing my problem

Comment: This is not possible with CSS because of how ancestry works. You could certainly do it in JavaScript or PHP.

Comment: The question is why you want to apply a semantically contiguous style to non-contiguous results. Why don't you just put all the `li` elements in one `ul`?

Comment: @TylerH each ul has it's own style indicating the severity of the list contents, they're still compact enough that it makes sense to style the list items together (I think). I think I might go with a javascript solution then

Comment: @Bryan Yeah, even if you put the ULs into a LI wrapper you'd still run into the ancestry problem (e.g. 'x-child' is 'child of *its* parent'), so yeah I would recommend JavaScript to loop through each instance of li within a wrapper or on the whole page (however you have the markup), iterating a counter and applying one of two styles based on whether the counter is even or odd. Edit - AKA exactly like what sweaver2112 did now that I see his answer, lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if there's a css solution, but you could use some javascript to do this:

```js
var els = document.querySelectorAll("li");
for (i = 0; i < els.length; ++i) {
  i % 2 == 0? els[i].style.color = "green" : els[i].style.color = "red"
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li>text</li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li>text</li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li>text</li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li>text</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Shame there's not a CSS solution, that code works great though. Thank you.

Comment: @sweaver See my comments above; there's definitely not a CSS solution for this, until the day they decide to put in a "grandchild" selector that lets you explicitly skip one (or a set, arbitrary amount of) level of descendants. At any rate, your solution is exactly what I suggested to the OP before I read your answer. Something something great minds... :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to apply a odd/even CSS style to this li, then you can use the `nth-child(odd)` or `nth-child(even)` however, you want this on the ul, not the li.  If you put it on the li then it will apply the styling to the odd/even children of the li.

```
ul.topLevel > li:nth-child(odd);
ul.topLevel > li:nth-child(even);
```

Comment: Hey I should have included what I had tried previously before but did not. It's included now and I have tried that without success. My sample has a ul with a single li inside, a second ul with 3 items inside (Where I see it alternating), and then three ul's with a single item inside each. So I get {Color 1}, {Color 1, Color 2, Color 1}, {Color 1}, {Color 1}, {Color 1}. Hope I explained that well